# A Runnable is quietly dying, executing the outer finally, and giving no other clue. How can I see what caused the thread to die

Tags: java, multithreading

My code essentially does something like this:

```
public void run() {
   try {
      while(true) {
         // Do a bunch of stuff with
         // Kafka and Redis over the 
         // network.
      }
   }
   catch (Exception outerE) {
      System.out.println("I never print this.");
   }
   finally {
      System.out.println("I always print this.");
   }
}
```

Something is causing the thread to die, but it isn't falling out of the while loop, and it isn't triggering an Exception, but I do see the message from the finally.

What is the best way to identify what killed a thread?

It is running under a ThreadPoolExecutor, so I can't just add an uncaughtExceptionHandler to the thread.

The first idea that works gets a bounty as soon as I can assign one.

Edit:  So the "finally" clause let me know that it was breaking without an Exception.  A few hours after I posted this, I did indeed use a custom thread factory to add an uncaught handler to the threads and it turned out to be a deadly mix of a self-referential Avro record with the Confluent Kafka Schema Registry.  It was causing infinite recursion and blowing out the stack.

At my shop, it is utterly impossible to get a "catch (Throwable t)" into production, as it is considered a bad idea, even though, in this case, it is exactly the idea that is needed.  But still, utterly impossible or I would have tried that.

Comment: print something after the while loop to 10000% make sure that the while loop is not `breaking`

Comment: Why not log the state of things from within the loop, and after the loop exits

Comment: You need to post the threadpool configuration and how the caller code is waiting for completion.

Comment: Don’t know why you couldn't assign an uncaught exception handler, have the executor use a custom thread factory.

Comment: Seriously?  A hold?  In cases where the error is unknown, like this one, a "specific problem or error" is not possible to state, if it were, that would contain the answer and no question would be necessary.  This was a general question about thread death, and a request for suggestions, some of which were quite good.

Comment: Agree. I voted to re-open. I think there was enough context to answer.

Comment: That was a simplified loop, I am infinity% sure the while loop was not breaking.  I am logging the state of things, until everything mysteriously disappears and finally gets called and the thread dies. the loop never exits, that's one of the things that makes it weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be that this `Throwable` is a type of `Error` and not a standard `Exception`

[image]

Try this:

```
public void run() {
   try {
      while(true) {
         ...
      }
   } catch (final Throwable t) {
      System.out.println("I never print this.");
   } finally {
      System.out.println("I always print this.");
   }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of that too, but I'm not sure if it is advisable to catch an `Error` though.

Comment: @Jai Agreed, but sometimes you need complete assurance. For this type of error I would usually `catch>log>rethrow`

Comment: This actually would have been my preferred solution, but no way to get that into production given the shop standards.  I used a custom thread factory to add an unhandled exception handler to dump the thread and it took me straight to an open issue on Github.

Comment: If you know the exact error type that needs to be checked for, then you can catch just that instead of all Throwable or Error. IMO that wouldn't be a major evil if the error is mostly transient and unavoidable

Comment: It's buried about three libraries deep, but I'll get those people to check for it.  I'm kinda annoyed at Oracle/Sun for the whole "never catch Errors" and then "we will quietly just pretend Errors didn't happen"....I'd much rather see my entire JVM crash with a stack trace telling me that I didn't handle a StackOverflow then to try and hunt and guess.